# Why doesn't width:auto work

Tags: html, css

I have a site that I developed, using MAMP, and on my localhost, it worked fine; but, when I uploaded it to the server, `width:auto` stopped working. By stopped working I mean that it doesn't wrap all the elements like it use to. Now rather than having a line of `gallery-image`, the width matches the parent element.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="gallery-wrapper">

        <div id="gallery-images">

             <?php foreach($content1 as $img) : ?>
                <div class="gallery-image-holder">
                    <a class="gallery-image" href="<?php echo "/images/".$img['url'];?>"> <img src="<?php echo "/images/".$img['url'];?>" /></a>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach;?>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#gallery-wrapper{
    width:37em;
    height:11em;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 1.5em;
    float:left;

}
#gallery-images{
    display: inline-block;
    width:auto;
    height:11em;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    margin-right: .5em;
    position:relative;
    padding:0 !important;

}

.gallery-image-holder{
    display: inline-block;
    width:12.5em;
    height:11em;
    margin:.25em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: More info, like what it was was doing before, what is it doing now. Stopped working is not a description of your problem.

Comment: Updated. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: THe problem is probably because of inline-block;

Comment: That didn't fix it. Thank you though.

Comment: Is this how it currently looks for you? ->  http://jsfiddle.net/T6P4T/7/

Comment: @Smith Yes! That is is! `#gallery-images` use to display all the images inline and would extend across, hidden under the other element. This is for a slider, so each image should be inline.

Comment: Is this what you had before? -> http://jsfiddle.net/T6P4T/15/

Comment: @Smith Kind of. Without the vertical scrolling.

Comment: There won't be a vertical scroll bar if you know the width of the images and the number. Just multiply the width of each image plus it's  side margin times the number of images and set the .gallery-images width to that.

Comment: @smith I meant horizontal scrolling bar. And that doesn't help if I need to add more images. Looking for a dynamic result. It use to work on my localhost, but now it doesn't.

Comment: CSS doesn't change with domains. It is browser dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Best thing I can suggest is something like this.

```
current = $(#gallery-wrapper).innerWidth()
$(#gallery-wrapper).css('width',auto)
new = $(#gallery-wrapper).innerWidth()
$(#gallery-wrapper).css('width',current+"px")
$(#gallery-wrapper).animate({'width':new},speed)
```

There are better solutions out there but this is what I would do. If you want to toggle it could get very confusing as this would have to be done in reverse and would have to work out a current state.